# Rugby penalty kick into touch-in-goal

Tags: rules, rugby-union

In Rugby Union, when a penalty is taken as a kick into touch, imagine the following two situations:

[Penalties http://www.die-sinlosen.de/fred/rugbykick.png](http://www.die-sinlosen.de/fred/rugbykick.png)

1. The kick goes over the try line (I think this is called in-goal?), but then into the touch area (over the field's side line) before touching the ground.
2. The kick goes over the try line and over the end of the field.

What happens in these cases? Which team will have possession?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both cases the defending team would be offered the option of a 22m drop out or a scrum back at the point the kick was taken from.  This is the same as for any kick.  This would only apply for kicks not at goal.

If it had been signaled as a kick at goal both would result in a 22m drop out for the defending team.

These scenarios are covered by [law 22.8](http://laws.worldrugby.org/index.php?law=22).